# Python script that maps natural numbers to lattices in a spiral-like manner

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

This is a Python script that maps natural numbers to lattice points in a spiral like manner. It maps all natural numbers to all points with integer coordinates, and it produces a list of coordinates of the first `n` vertices in the spiral for given input `n`.

The spiral is grown in such a manner, start at the origin, go right and extend the length of arm by one, go up, go left and increment the length, go down and repeat.

The input is an `int`eger, and the output is a `deque` of two element `tuple`s, each element being an `int`, they represent the x, y coordinates of the vertex located at the index where the element appears.

```py
from collections import deque
from functools import reduce
from itertools import cycle, repeat
from operator import iconcat
from statistics import mean, stdev
from timeit import timeit
from typing import Deque, Generator, Tuple


ROLL = ((1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (-1, 0, 1), (0, -1, 0))


def rolls_needed(n: int) -> float:
    return ((4 * n + 1) ** 0.5 - 1) / 4


def roll_length(n: float) -> int:
    return round(4 * n * n + 2 * n)


def arms_needed(n: int, k: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    k *= 2
    for a, b in ((4, 6), (3, 4), (2, 2), (1, 1)):
        if n >= (c := a * k + b):
            return a, n - c
    return 0, n


def calc_arms(n: int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    rolls = int(rolls_needed(n))
    arms = extra = 0
    if (length := roll_length(rolls)) < n:
        arms, extra = arms_needed(n - length, rolls)
    return 4 * rolls + arms, extra


def walk(pos: int, sign: int, steps: int) -> Tuple[range, int]:
    end = pos + sign * (steps + 1)
    return range(pos + sign, end, sign), end - sign


def follow(pos: int, sign: int, steps: int) -> Tuple[range | repeat, int]:
    return walk(pos, sign, steps) if sign else (repeat(pos), pos)


class Ulamish_Spiral:
    def reset(self):
        self.roll = cycle(ROLL)
        self.xc = 0
        self.yc = 0
        self.length = 0

    def next(self):
        self.dx, self.dy, self.widen = next(self.roll)
        if self.widen:
            self.length += 1

    def next_arm(self, length: int) -> zip:
        (arm_x, self.xc), (arm_y, self.yc) = \
            follow(self.xc, self.dx, length), follow(self.yc, self.dy, length)
        return zip(arm_x, arm_y)

    def spiral_gen(self, n: int) -> Generator:
        self.reset()
        arms, extra = calc_arms(n)
        for _ in range(arms):
            self.next()
            yield self.next_arm(self.length)
        if extra:
            self.next()
            yield self.next_arm(extra)

    def get_coordinates(self, n: int) -> Deque[Tuple[int, int]]:
        return reduce(iconcat, self.spiral_gen(n), deque([(0, 0)]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    u = Ulamish_Spiral()
    time = [timeit(lambda: u.get_coordinates(2550), number=10) /
            10 for _ in range(1000)]
    print(f"{mean(time)*1e6:.2f} ± {stdev(time)*1e6:.2f} μs")
```

The runtime of the script to get the first 2550 points is 310.56 ± 48.88 μs. 2550 is the total number of points on the first 100 arms, which complete 25 loops.

I have achieved everything I intended to, and I have spend sufficient time on it I want a review. The script is just an exercise to practice my skills.

It seems the algorithm is as efficient as possible, and I have tried to optimize it in any and all methods I can think of, though perhaps there are still methods I am not aware of.

I don't know if it can be more efficient, but if I have hit the performance bottleneck, perhaps the script can be more concise and readable, and I don't like the way the variables are organized and shared between the functions.

How can I improve it?

---

Desired output for `n = 20`:

```
deque([(0, 0),
       (1, 0),
       (1, 1),
       (0, 1),
       (-1, 1),
       (-1, 0),
       (-1, -1),
       (0, -1),
       (1, -1),
       (2, -1),
       (2, 0),
       (2, 1),
       (2, 2),
       (1, 2),
       (0, 2),
       (-1, 2),
       (-2, 2),
       (-2, 1),
       (-2, 0),
       (-2, -1),
       (-2, -2)])
```

The natural numbers are integers from 0 on, lattice points are all points (x, y) where both x and y are integers, and both x and y are signed, so they span four quadrants.

Both sets are countably infinite, and they have the same cardinality, which means their sizes are equal, because there are one-to-one mappings between the two sets, each element in one set is uniquely mapped to an element in the other with no leftovers.

The spiral is one such one-to-one mapping, the function generates a finite slice of the infinite sequence, the first n + 1 vertices in the spiral, which is the origin plus the first n coordinates for the positive numbers.

English is not my first language, and I am not good with words, so I will show you the meaning of the desired output:

[image]

And there was a small bug in the script that caused the output to misalign with the intended result, I have fixed it.

---

As for the calculations, if each successive four right, up, left and down arms constitute a roll, then the first n rolls will have 4n<sup>2</sup>+2n points (not counting the origin), and on nth roll, the number of points on each arm would be R: 2n+1, U: 2n+1, L: 2n+2, D: 2n+2. ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/163093/1061426))

`rolls_needed` calculates the number of rolls required to get n points, using basic algebra. The return value is a fraction, the integer part is the number of whole rolls. The difference between the number of points contained in the whole rolls and the total requested points is then calculated again using the basic algebra.

The extra points that aren't enough for another roll, is again subdivided into whole arms and extra points that aren't enough to justify another arm, this time using iteration.

The number of arms is the number of whole rolls times 4 plus the number of whole arms, I do this because my method is based on generating the whole arms according to the rules, to reduce conditional checkings, and to remove extra computations.

The remaining number of points is the length of the partial arm that is added, to meet the requested number of points. In this way there are no extra computations and iterations, no wasted execution time.

Comment: What is `arms_needed` supposed to return (what are those two components)? The type hint is incorrect and I don't understand the data in context.

Comment: The same is true of `calc_arms` where you hint one return value but return two

Comment: It's worth adding documentation as to why this is only Ulam-ish (it's because you don't mark primes).